# writing an SQL query

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I wrote this query but it's not executing

```
ResultSet rs6 = stmt.executeQuery(
    "UPDATE customer SET BALANCE = BALANCE + amount WHERE MOBILENUMBER = '"+phone+"' ");
rs6.next();
System.out.print("your account balance is  " +rs6.getString("BALANCE"));
```

amount is a `double`

what's wrong with it?

Comment: Make sure that [Little Bobby Table](http://xkcd.com/327/) is not setting the value of that `phone` variable through a web application :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) for updates. The result of which will return the number of rows updated (not some arbitrarily updated columns new value). In order to get the new balance you are going to need to execute a follow up query.

Also, use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), they are good, really.

Comment: By follow-up query I mean run a select query after the update to get the new information.

Answer (score 0):

you just committed update command, not select command, so you cannot get the balance

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` statements do not (usually) return a result. If you really want to update the data, you should use `executeUpdate()` instead. It will return the number of rows affected by the update.

If you actually want to retrieve the rows specified by the where condition, you should use a `SELECT` statement. That will return a ResultSet that you can loop through.

Answer (score 0):

Update queries do not return results.  You will need to update in one statement and select in a second.  Also, please use parameterized queries - something like this would be better

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE customer SET BALANCE = BALANCE + ? WHERE MOBILENUMBER = ?");

stmt.setDouble(1, amount);
stmt.setString(2, phone);

stmt.execute();
stmt.close();

stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT BALANCE from customer where MOBILENUMBER = ?");
stmt.setString(1, phone);

ResultSet rs6 = stmt.execute();
rs6.next();
System.out.print("your account balance is " +rs6.getString("BALANCE"));

rs6.close();
stmt.close();
```